# Return first value of an array that matches an element from a different array

Tags: arrays, ruby, find

I would like to compare two arrays and return the first value of array 1 that matches an item from array two.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def find_the_color(array_1)
  array_2 = ["red", "yellow", "blue"]
  sample.find do |x|
    x=="red"||x=="yellow"||x=="blue"
  end
end
```

I would like to do this using the array instead of separating it into 3 conditional statements.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this

```
 array_1.find { |x| array_2.include?(x) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_1 = [ 'green', 'yellow' ]
array_2 = ["red", "yellow", "blue"]
( array_1 & array_2 ).first
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important, first convert `array_2` to a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

```
array_1 = %w{ green yellow orange purple mauve black blue }
array_2 = %w{ pink red mauve white brown }

require 'set'

set_2 = array_2.to_set
array_1.find { |e| set_2.include? e }
  #=> "mauve"
```

By converting `array_2` to a set at the onset, `set_2.include? e` can be executed quickly (similar to looking up the value of a hash key). By contrast, with [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), `array_2` must be enumerated for each element of `array_1` until a match is found.